# Eclipse m2e - No Such File or Directory in pom.xml

Tags: eclipse, maven, pom.xml, m2e

I'm using Eclipse 4.5.2 (Mars.2 JEE), Eclipse Maven m2e v1.7.0 (20160603-1933) plugin, Java 8 multi-module project on Linux RedHat.

My project structure is the following:

- Parent project containing pom.xml
- Module A which doesn't depend on any project in Eclipse Workspace. Contains only 3PP dependencies in pom.xml (Guava, Apache Commons,
  SLF4J...)
- Module B which contains Module A, and 3PP dependencies (Guava, Apache Commons, SLF4J...).

Structure is:

```
parent-project
|-- pom.xml // only this file
|
|--module-a
|  |-- pom.xml
|  | code
|
|--module-b
   |-- pom.xml // contains Module A as dependency
```

The problem I'm getting (in Eclipse, under "Markers") is:

**"Maven Configuration Problem" -> No such file or directory    pom.xml /module-b   line 1  Maven Configuration Problem**

Since I didn't have any issue reported in module-a, I've removed module-a from the module-b dependencies and the above problem is cleared away.

This led me to: **It seems that the m2e gets confused when it comes to resolution of one workspace project as other other project dependency.** Now, the code is working perfectly well in runtime, but I would like to get rid of this annoyance.

**What I've tried:**

- I've tried Eclipse installing Maven plugin v1.6.2 in fresh eclipse
  installation (deleted eclipse and workspace directories before...
  lost some time reinstalling) - no luck.
- I've tried to use Eclipse
  v4.6.2 (Neon.2) and the same issue appears (before, I've deleted
  eclipse and workspace directories and created new ones... again,
  spent some time).
- Stackoverflow suggestion: Disable workspace
  resolution in individual project settings. I find this unacceptable
  since I need to lose time installing all dependent projects in order
  for the "module-b" look-alike project to work cleanly.
- Running **mvn
  clean eclipse:clean**, eclipse restart + Maven update - no help.

Has anyone found similar issues? Any suggestions?

Comment: Prevent using `mvn eclipse:XXX` cause it's long deprecated. Furthermore does you project work without any issue from command line? Have you tried to build on command line via: `mvn clean package`?

Comment: The project and maven jobs (i.e clean package) work absolutely fine both from command line and eclipse. Therefore, I suspected that the m2e runtime wasn't working well since it's basically reporting non-existing error.

Also, tried "mvn clean package" from command line as suggested, then refreshed all eclipse projects. Didn't help :(

Comment: have you found a solution (without disabling workspace resolution)?

Answer (score 3):

For me the root cause of this was [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=359522) bug. If you are in an environment where your temporary directory is shared (e.g. /tmp on Linux), and two or more different users happen to open Eclipse and use M2E to build, then the error occurs. Somewhere in M2E it writes to /tmp/fakerepo, so whichever user gets to write here first gets to own the folder and breaks Eclipse for any other users.

A reboot will often fix the problem (/tmp gets cleared), or simply remove this temporary folder yourself as an administrator before starting Eclipse.

Comment: More details on how to work around this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51324406/1800052