# How to specify a unique java.io.tmpdir for each user of a multi-user Eclipse installation?

Tags: eclipse, multi-user

I have an Eclipse installation on a multi-user Linux system at `/opt/eclipse/`.

Unfortunately, because of a [defect in m2eclipse-mavenarchiver](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537003), this plugin uses a folder in a system temporary directory that is common for all users (this manifests as a "permission denied" message for a `pom.xml` file).

I planned to specify a unique value for `java.io.tmpdir` in a common `eclipse.ini` based on a user name, but it turned out that it is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51322680/1800052).

One option is to have a per-user installation of Eclipse where each `eclipse.ini` would have its [own value](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg04191.html) of `java.io.tmpdir` (e.g., `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/eclipse/john_doe`).

Is that possible to have a single multi-user Eclipse installation but somehow specify a unique value for `java.io.tmpdir` for each user?

Comment: Have you considered launching Eclipse through a custom system script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested in my comment that you could make your own custom script to launch Eclipse. Even in a way that *the same script* may serve for every user:

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -vmargs -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/eclipse/$USER
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@Little Santi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4040817/little-santi) advises in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51324406/how-to-specify-a-unique-java-io-tmpdir-for-each-user-of-a-multi-user-eclipse-ins?noredirect=1#comment89655366_51324406), a customized per-user launcher can be used. You could specify the desired path as [a command-line argument for a JVM](https://help.eclipse.org/photon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html):

```
/opt/eclipse/eclipse -vmargs -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/eclipse/john_doe
```

To be on the safe side, make sure the specified directory exists and has correct ownership and access rights.